Will the last launch of the Delta rocket family cause changes to the liquid hydrogen supply chain?
This is a question from outside the StackExchange network that I'm reposting with permission from the original author. I honestly don't know if I think it's more likely to get answered here or on Mastodon.

Will the end of the Delta rocket mean an increased price for Centaur and SLS? The Delta program had continuous funding irrespective of launch to support things like the liquid hydrogen supply chain. Centaur is a much smaller rocket, and SLS launches, to a first approximation, never. So who is paying to maintain all the hydrogen trucks, tanks, liquefiers?
Hydrogen itself is a fairly common industrial chemical, but my impression (maybe wrong) is that liquid hydrogen is rare and weird.

I think the core question(s) here can probably be answered with hard facts on if the government has rebid liquid hydrogen supply contracts, or with press releases from a company like Air Liquide or whoever is/are the main liquid hydrogen supplier(s).

I was just stuck behind a LOX truck on Fairmont Parkwy...VENTING IS NORMAL!

@OrganicMarble I used to love seeing the cryo trucks unload at the big vacuum chamber at JSC. Presumably we got some liquid methane in during the Morpheus tests too. Not sure if we ever had liquid hydrogen on site

Venting of LOX and LN2 is indeed entirely normal. The hydrogen tanks I know of for a semiconductor fab do not vent anything. They are the ‘torpedo tube’ variety, so I think is just high pressure gas.

It shouldn't be a big problem for US in particular because US (probably the only country) mass produces LH2 for industrial use (on the orders of one or two hundred tons per day). Japan and Germany might also have this capability on a lower scale( although their bet on H2 as the energy of the future might not be so successful). On the other hand, China is a counter example that lacks this capability, e.g. only one or a few H2 liquefies exists in China, and each with a capacity of only a few hundred liters per our.

Venting is normal for non-flammable gases. The Delta IV is famous for setting itself briefly on fire, when the hydrogen, that was used to start the engines, burns off at ignition. You definitely wouldn't want to be stuck in traffic behind a truck venting liquid -hydrogen boil-off.

Liquid hydrogen is neither rare or weird. While it’s true that outside of its use as a rocket fuel hydrogen is primarily used in gaseous form, hydrogen is often transported longer distances in a liquid state. And as pointed out by @Galerita hydrogen is often stored on-site as a liquid in order to reduce storage volume.
Hydrogen is transported by pipeline in gaseous form in a few regions of the U.S. where that infrastructure is in place, primarily Texas, Louisiana and Alabama (source: Hydrogen’s Present and Future in the U.S. Energy Sector). In other parts of the U.S. hydrogen is delivered by truck. For shorter distances like 200 miles or less it is transported in gaseous form in pressurized tube containers. Normally not a single container but multiple smaller containers.

Hydrogen tube trailer with eight pressurized cylinders (Wikimedia Commons, CC-BY-SA-4.0)
However for longer distances hydrogen is liquefied and then shipped in a single refrigerated container.

Liquid hydrogen trailer (ESG News)
As stated on the Department of Energy website:

Currently, for longer distances, hydrogen is transported as a liquid in super-insulated, cryogenic tanker trucks. After liquefaction, the liquid hydrogen is dispensed to delivery trucks and transported to distribution sites where it is vaporized to a high-pressure gaseous product for dispensing.

Over long distances, trucking liquid hydrogen is more economical than trucking gaseous hydrogen because a liquid tanker truck can hold a much larger mass of hydrogen than a gaseous tube trailer can. Challenges with liquid transportation include the potential for boil-off during delivery.

Hydrogen production in the U.S. is increasing, being used not only for industrial purposes but there is also a lot of interest in using hydrogen as a renewable energy source. Although most hydrogen production is currently not very ecologically friendly, many countries seem to be anxious to begin getting hydrogen infrastructure in place, ready for when cleaner hydrogen production methods become more economically viable. For example several projects around the U.S. are looking into the possibility of mixing a percentage of (gaseous) hydrogen into existing natural gas supplies. As another example, Air Products, one of NASA’s primary suppliers of hydrogen at its launch and engine testing facilities, is in a joint venture project to build the largest green hydrogen production facility in the United States.
There is also quite a lot of research being done especially in Europe for powering aircraft with liquid hydrogen.

Liquid hydrogen powered aircraft (Airbus)
While challenging, this will probably be more feasible than trying to power long haul aircraft with batteries which will likely be relegated to short-hop flights, since unlike consumable fuels batteries do not lose weight during flight.
I don't know what percentage of liquid hydrogen is produced for end-use operations like rocket fuel, how much is liquified for on-site storage (even if it will be used as a gas), and how much is liquified solely for transport even though it will be stored in gaseous form. But either way since the production of liquid hydrogen is already common for multiple purposes, it seems unlikely that the end of Delta IV will have any noticeable direct effect on NASA's cost for liquid hydrogen.
As for NASA contracts for hydrogen, the most recent that I could find was a contract awarded to Air Products in March 2023. Air Products has been supplying hydrogen to NASA since 1957.

Air Products hydrogen trailer (Air Products)
This seems to be an add-on to a contract awarded to both Air Products and Linde Inc. a few months earlier in November 2022 for supplying hydrogen to KSC, CCSFS, Marshall, Stennis, Glenn, and Armstrong.
As pointed out by @ErinAnne the linked Air Products press release mentions upcoming projects that will each produce many tens of tons of liquid hydrogen on a daily basis.
Air Liquide seems to only supply liquid nitrogen to NASA.

Thorough answer, +1. The Air Products press release also talks about a lot of infrastructure investment being done in new liquid hydrogen plants, amounting to hundreds of tons more liquid hydrogen per day. That feels more substantive than some of what I turned up in my own searches, which seemed more like "invest in us today and there might be liquid hydrogen next...decade?"

An SLS core stage has 144 tonnes of liquid hydrogen as part of its propellant mass, about 14.6% of its total fuel mass and about  13.3% of the gross mass of the stage. Using similar proportions, the second stage has ~4.2 tonnes of LH2. Side bar here.
The gross mass of a Delta IV core stage is 226.4 t. If 13.3% is LH2, that corresponds to 30.1 t LH2, or 90 tonnes for the 3 common booster cores.
At peak there were 4 Delta IV launches per year of all variants, in 2012, 14 and 16, suggesting a consumption of <400 tonnes LH2 per year for the Delta IV.
US LH2 consumption is estimated to be 42,300 tonnes in 2024, and growing at a rate of ~5.7% per year (~2,400 t).
An example is Linde, one of the two largest producers of industrial gases globally (along with Air Liquide). Here's a Linde presentation on their H2 industry. Page 8 (7 in the search box) claims they have 5 hydrogen liquifiers (LH2) in the US with a capacity of more than 150,000 kg a day, which is ~55,000 tonnes annually. (I assume it's capacity rather than actual production.)
Even at the peak rate of Delta IV launches, LH2 use for this vehicle was only ~1% of current US LH2 consumption, suggesting the space industry is a niche application, well behind industrial uses.
@StevePemberton discusses the two means of road transport of hydrogen. In pressurised tube form a 30,000 kg gross mass tractor-trailer can only deliver only 400 kg of H2 gas, while a 40,000 kg gross mass tractor-trailer can deliver 2,100 kg as LH2, more than 5 times as much. (See the table on page 18 of the linked document.) It is this poor payload to vehicle mass ratio that accounts for the preference of transporting H2 in liquid form over long distances.
The retirement of the Delta IV rocket family will cause little effect on US LH2 supply chain. Annual growth alone is several times the highest consumption of the space industry. I suspect the LH2 industry would welcome an extra customer.

I wonder if there is more supporting documentation out there about LH2 use. The  statista.com page is a bit vague, although sources are apparently available behind their paywall. I wonder if they mistakenly simply counted liquefaction output and assumed that all of the LH2 would be used in that state, not realizing that much of it is in a liquid state only for transport. Also their statement about fuel-cell vehicles is not correct, fuel-cell vehicles use pressurized hydrogen, at least the ones that I am familiar with.

@StevePemberton I hope the link to you works now.

I'm a chemical engineer, at least I was. Vast amounts of hydrogen - by far the majority of production (~90%) - is used in industrial processes in to produce ammonia, refine petroleum and  and to produce methanol. When this is not manufactured on site, transport is either by pipeline, or as a liquid in trails or trucks. If it's stored on site it is as a liquid, as large pressure vessels must have very thick walls and have much less volume than liquid storage.

@StevePemberton
H2 can be stored as an intermediate chemical dissolved in ammonia, but even this is done cryogenically. There are other chemical means of storing hydrogen, but regenerating it (removing it from its chemical form) is problematic. These are mostly research technologies.

H2 used in motor vehicles can be stored as either a liquid or a gas. Personally I think Toyota has the right approach with its carbon fibre composite tanks storing H2 at ambient pressure, which are much lighter than equivalent steel tanks. But the storage pressure is only 70 MPa. Four unobtrusive tanks still give the Toyota Mirai, 500 km+ range, but H2 powered vehicles are a very limited application for H2.

"Cryogenic liquid storage tanks, also referred to as dewars, are the most common way to store large quantities of hydrogen.". Ammonia, petroleum and methanol industries have on-site storage of lathe amounts of LH2 to prevent interruption of their core production..
Is this level of detail worth adding to the original answer?

Yes I think mentioning on-site storage of LH2 is worth adding to my answer so I will do that. It's sort of an interesting semantics distinction about what constitutes usage.  Without other qualifiers I'm guessing that most people would interpret "usage" as meaning the end result use, not the storage method, but maybe that's just how I was thinking about it. I wonder what the breakdown is between LH2 produced just for transport, for storage, and for end result usage. By the way I own a Honda Clarity PHEV, the original Clarity was a FCEV, the slightly odd shape of my car reflects that somewhat.

I expect H2 FCEVs  will ultimately replace EVs,because 1) batteries in EVs are very heavy (energy density is poor + vehicle heavy) & 2) batteries in EVs contain toxic materials that are hard to recycle.
The big issue is FCEV require sufficient refill infrastructure to be viable, & that infrastructure is expensive. Even so, LH2 storage at refill stations is preferred with greater demand.
It's cheaper to store large quantities of H2 cryogenically.  H2 gas tanks are small, heavy & thick walled.

I was thinking of the total LH2 produced for whatever ultimate use, bearing in mind that some can be diverted for the space industry. If it's abundant there is no problem diverting some & it's fairly cheap. If its rarely produced then dedicated infrastructure is required, which is relevant to the "supply chain" in the original question & it will be more expensive.

For sure which is the reason that I mentioned LH2 produced solely for transport. I agree LH2 produced for storage would have a similar effect on availability. I was just addressing the fact that some people would be like me and read the statista headline "Consumption of liquid hydrogen" and assume (erroneously) that a lot more than just rocket engines use hydrogen in liquid form. Although when you think about it many hydrolox engines are essentially using gaseous hydrogen (i.e. boiled LH2). It's more about storage space in the tanks to use LH2. Although it can also be used for engine cooling.

+1, but I also don't like that statista source much (it's the first one I found too). Hard to trust sources behind a paywall. But I believe it overall

@ErinAnne I agree. I'm not paying to get Statistica references. (I can get them through work if absolutely necessary, but then I can't share them.)
Linde and Air Liquide are the two largest global producers of industrial gases globally. Here's a Linde presentation on their H2 industry. Page 8 (7 in the search box) claims they have 5 hydrogen liquifiers in the US with a capacity of more than 150,000 kg a day, which is ~55,000 tonnes.

@ErinAnne I added the link to the Linde presentation to the main answer.
HTH
